# How to output a .exe file using a program(which in itself is an exe file) in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, exe

So this must be easy but quite difficult to search online. All the results give me the answer to how to make an exe file out of a C# program.

Motive:- To make an exe file which runs a random episode of any TV series.

I have made a new WPF application in C# through Visual Studio which asks the user to select a folder, and then runs a random video from all the files in that folder and its sub-folders. But I do not want the user to always go and select the folder. What should I include in the code, for it to save an exe file somewhere with the directory selected by the user. And then the user can conveniently run that file itself.
Here is my code:

```
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
        string files="a"; //Initialize


        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //If user presses OK then, 'files' variable is the directory selected
            files = fbd.SelectedPath; 
        }
        else if(result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Close();
        }

        //All Important Video Formats Included to search for
        string[] formats = { "mp4", "avi", "mkv", "flv", "wmv", "3gp" };
        string[] Allfiles = new string[0];
        for (int i=0; i<formats.Length;i++)
        {
            string[] temp = Directory.GetFiles(files, "*" + formats[i], SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            Allfiles = AddArray(Allfiles, temp);
        }

        //Starts a random Episode
        Random episode = new Random();
        int Episode = episode.Next(0, Allfiles.Length);
        Process.Start(Allfiles[Episode]);
```

Comment: Do you want your application as .exe or your app make .exe app

Comment: Why can't users just copy your exe file to a folder they want and then this exe files plays a random video from its location?

Comment: This is a strange program. How about a `.bat` which starts your exe with the folder as parameter?

Comment: Agree w/ @Rabban. Why would you use a compiled binary (exe) for this purpose? A batch file can simply be written as text, with a `.bat` extension, and do what you describe.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: @RazLuvaton I want my application to be an exe. When I will run it, it will ask me to select a folder. Now I want this exe(my application) to output a new exe (which I can save somewhere) which has this selected folder path as an input. Now this new exe should run any random video from that folder path by just running it.

Comment: @Rabban I want the app to run on any system. For that, the user has to specify the folder path and I can't do that by changing the parameter. Please let me know if I am making a mistake here. I am not much aware of .bat functioning.

Comment: @Kirhgoph It wont be user friendly because the user would have to anyway go to the folder where the video files are. I want the file to be on desktop. I personalized it for my personal PC by putting the folder path directly in the code, but that's not a universal solution.

Comment: You'd normally store your user preferences e.g. in the registry or some configuration file.

Comment: @AntrikshJohri what's about creating a new program that's run a random video instead of the code creating a new one

Comment: Where is the code that you want to compile at runtime? Anyway you could use `CSharpCodeProvider` class to build your assembly at runtime.

Comment: @RazLuvaton But how will I include the folder path that the user has selected? Because I will be using this folder path later on to run the video.

Comment: You can write it into a text file and then read it in the other application

Comment: @RazLuvaton Okay I get it. So I will need to applications. I will run the first one, and get the folder path and write it to a file. Then I will start the second one and read from that file. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @SimoneCifani This is the WPF code-behind file. And how will building the assembly at runtime solve the purpose?

Comment: @AntrikshJohri yes, and you can close your application when opening the second one by `this.Close()`

Comment: @RazLuvaton Awesome!! It works. Thanks a lot. I am new here, so can you tell me if I can give you some reputation or something for your answer?

Comment: @AntrikshJohri as comment no but I will post now the answer and you can give it the v sign, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can write it into a text file and then read it in the other application

Add `using System.IO;`

Write to a text file:

```
// Write the string to a file.
StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(txt path);
file.WriteLine(lines);

file.Close();
```

Read from a text file:

```
String line;
try 
{
//Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Sample.txt");

//Read the first line of text
line = sr.ReadLine();

//close the file
sr.Close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
}
   finally 
{
Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
}
```

If you want to close the app just type `this.Close()`